# JNB after comparison with 0 (x86)

Tags: assembly, x86

I have this x86 assembly code:

```
mov     [ebp+var_8], 0

mov     eax, Str_len

cmp     [ebp+var_8], eax

jnb     short loc_4018C4
```

If Str_len is always different from 0, what does this JNB perform ? My reasoning is that if Str_len variable is never below than 0, the jump is never perform, right ?

Btw, how can a register have values below than zero in binary representation of x86 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jnb` (really an alias for `jnc`) uses one of the "unsigned predicates", so with respect to `jnb`, a value is never below zero.

But the thing that is zero is the first argument to the comparison, so it's really computing  `0 - eax` (and then it keeps only the flags, not the result), and then it jumps if there is no carry. So it comes down to: jump if `Str_len` is zero.

Answer (score 5):

`jnb` instruction jumps when the carry flag is zero. The `cmp` instruction updates the flags according to the result of the subtraction of `src` operand from the `dst` operand. The `dst` operand is the first operand in the Intel notation, thus, the flags will be updated according to the result of `[ebp+var_8]-eax`. As `[ebp+var_8]` equals to zero the carry flag will be cleared when when `eax` is zero and set otherwise. To summarize, the branch will happen when `eax` is equal to zero.